# How can I add a featured image from a blog post to my homepage on shopify

Tags: ruby, e-commerce, shopify, liquid

here is my code so far:

```
{% for article in blogs["field-notes"].articles limit: 2 %}
<li>{{ article.title | link_to: article.url }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

What I want to do is have the blog post featured image as the background of the li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the featured image using [article.image or article.image.src](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/article#article-image), and you can also use the [img_url filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#img_url) to get the appropriate size of that image.

```
{% for article in blogs["field-notes"].articles %}
    <li style="background-image:url({{ article.image.src | img_url: 'medium' }});">
        <a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```